# Self-made function works in test but not for my actual data set

Tags: r, function, tree

I am working with functions. I wrote a function for Basal Area

```
 ba <- function(dbh,na.rm) {
 stopifnot(is.numeric(dbh))
  answer <- dbh^2*(0.005454)
  return(answer)
  }
```

The function works with a test vector. Now I am trying to do some summaries of a dataset I have.

(copy and pasted directly from R)

```
plot.summary <- trees %>% group_by(MU, Plot, Inv) %>% summarize(year = first(Year), arithemtic.mean = my.mean(dbh, na.rm = TRUE), quadratic.mean = my.q.mean(dbh, na.rm = TRUE), var = my.var(dbh, na.rm = TRUE), n.trees = n())
```

(Modified spacing to read easier)

```
plot.summary <- trees %>% group_by(MU, Plot, Inv) %>% 
summarize(year = first(Year), arithemtic.mean = my.mean(dbh, na.rm = TRUE),
quadratic.mean = my.q.mean(dbh, na.rm = TRUE), var = my.var(dbh, na.rm = TRUE), 
n.trees = n())
```

When I run it is says

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
Column `basal.area` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 19
```

I am not sure why. The data set has only 18 columns.
My command works perfectly fine when I do not include the basal area part.

I am not sure what I might be missing

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Looks like you function returns a vector as long as its input. `summarize` is made for aggregate functions (like `mean`) that return a single value. So you get an error "*Column `basal.area` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 19*" when you get a result of length `19` instead of the expected length `1`. You can use `mutate` instead of `summarize` to keep the same number of rows instead of aggregating the data to 1-row-per-group.

Comment: So since I am grouping some of the data first my function is trying to get an individual basal area for each row now averaging it for each "group"?

Comment: Also I tried to do mutate `plot.summary <- trees %>% group_by(MU, Plot, Inv) %>% summarize(year = first(Year), arithemtic.mean = my.mean(dbh, na.rm = TRUE), quadratic.mean = my.q.mean(dbh, na.rm = TRUE), var = my.var(dbh, na.rm = TRUE), n.trees = n()) %>% mutate(basal.area = ba(dbh, na.rm= TRUE))`  and R returned `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column 'basal.area' must be length 3 (the group size) or one, not 4`

Comment: Can you post a little bit of sample data along with your desired outcome? 2-3 rows each for 2 groups should be plenty.

Answer (score 0):

The variables you refer to in the `group_by` function are not in the dataset `trees`, so I've taken some liberties to create a reproducible example that hopefully fits your needs.

Assuming you wanted to group by a variable like `Height`, here is a working example:

```
plot.summary <- trees %>% 
  group_by(Height) %>% 
  summarise(mean.basal.area = mean(ba(Girth)),
    n.trees = n())
```

In the above, your function `ba` is wrapped in `mean`. This results in a mean basal area for the set of values of Girth that share the same Height.

Is that the kind of thing you want?